# How to get value from matching in grouping by name?

Tags: c#, regex

```
    string input = "aaaabbbccc12345677XXXXsfsfsrfsd";
    MessageBox.Show(Regex.Match(input, "7(?<x1>.*)s").Groups["x1"].Value);
```

### That Result

---

### 7XXXXsfsfsrf

### OK

but i want XXXX  Value Only HOW?

```
   MessageBox.Show(Regex.Match(input, ".*7(?<x1>.*?)s").Groups["x1"].Value);
```

Comment: I cannot follow anymore. Can you update the question to give exactly what you have and what you want? The first problem was answered by me, the second one was answered by Mark Byers, but your last regular expression _should already work_ for the sample text given.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because after you changed your question my answer no longer makes sense (and neither does your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"7(?<x1>.*)s"
```

You need to use the right syntax: Naming a group works like this `(?<NameHere>ExpressionHere)`, see for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

Comment: +1, but I almost didn't see that; note `<?x1>` was replaced by `?<x1>`

Comment: Rubens: Yeah, I thought about a way to highlight that in the code (doesn't work as far as I can tell) and forgot to mention it in the text afterwards. Now it should be clear thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask your regex not to be too greedy

```
"7(?<x1>.*?)s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that regular expressions have longest-leftmost semantics. You seem to want the rightmost start with the leftmost end, so that's spelled

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Match(input, "^.*7(?<x1>.*?)s").Groups["x1"].Value);
```

The subpattern `^.*7` means “starting after the last `7` in the string…” Note that the caret (beginning of string) is redundant, but I like to use it for emphasis with `^.*x` meaning the last `x`.

In contrast, `.*?` means match as few characters as possible, starting with none.